# Is it possible to add a custom toolbox repository to the add-on explorer?

Tags: matlab, plugins, customization, add-on, toolbox

Is it possible to add a custom (potentially private) toolbox repository to the MATLAB Add-On Explorer? Something like this:

[image: add-on explorer]

In other words: is it possible to integrate a custom [binary repository manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_repository_manager) with MATLAB? Has anyone explored this possibility?

By default, MATLAB only searches the [File Exchange](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) or installed products from The MathWorks, but I'd like to add my own Toolbox repositor(y)(ies). I'm not finding anything related to this in any of the usual channels...

Comment: This is probably a broader question than you realise. The short answer, I think, is "no". The broad answer requires a recommendation to use the [Minimart](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59769-matlab-minimart) from the File Exchange, and to take a look at the JLR implementation of a MATLAB "store" as shown in [this blog](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/user_stories/jaguar-land-rover-standardizes-on-matlab-for-developing-packaging-and-sharing-engineering-tools.html).

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks, I suspected as much. (1) why not post this as an answer; it's likely the best possible one anyway (2) "broader than I realise": please enlighten me?

Comment: I know you didn't *ask* for an off-site recommendation, but that's what I've given, hence I gave it as a comment not an answer. "Hacking" the add on explorer with a custom configuration sounds like a pretty time consuming (and so broad) task, unless it's something documented which you probably would have already found, that's why I said it was broad. I'm not saying the question isn't *interesting*, but as currently posed I think it's broad and likely to garner only off-site recommendations, hence my initial comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This post is not a complete solution, but it addresses your questions, and points toward a possible solution path.

---

- Q: *Is it possible to invoke the add-on explorer programmatically?*

  A: Yes, it can be invoked using the Java API. There are several functions for invoking it:

  ```matlab
  com.mathworks.addons.AddonsLauncher.showExplorer("some_string");
  com.mathworks.addons.AddonsLauncher.showExplorerViewForHardwareSupportPackages("some_string");
  com.mathworks.addons.AddonsLauncher.showExplorerViewForApps("some_string");
  % etc.

  % See also: 
  %  1) "\MATLAB\R20###\java\jar\addons.jar"
  %  2) methods(com.mathworks.addons.AddonsLauncher.class)
  ```
- Q: *Is it possible to invoke the add-on explorer programmatically? Does that function take arguments?*

  A: See previous bullet. It does, but the argument doesn't do anything noticeable.
- Q: *Does it read configuration files?*

  A: It's hard to say without in-depth exploration of the `.jar` and the `.m` files that invoke it.
- Q: *Are there any insights or plans at The MathWorks to implement this in the near future?*

  A: N\A.
- Q: *Are there hints of that {plans to implement this} appearing in the MATLAB codebase?*

  A: Yes, the class `matlab.addons.repositories.FileExchangeRepository` appears to an implementation of such a repository connector (see also the `matlab.addons.repositories.SearchableAddonsRepository` superclass).

And finally,

- Q: *Is it possible to integrate a custom binary repository manager with MATLAB?*

  A: Based on the above, I would say **yes**.

My best guess would be to extend the Java class `com.mathworks.addons.NavigationData`, then instantiate it, and call `matlab.internal.addons.showExplorer(yourNavigationData)`.